# I can't remove a software package that needs to be removed to update my system

Tags: kubuntu, kde, discover-software-center

This is preventing me from updating my system and also making app installations fail.
The package name is linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic.
I am on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

EDIT:
As requested:

To find kernel version (after quick web search for console command):

uname -r

```
5.15.0-27-generic
```

The message I get after I start an update is in Discover dialog window that opens up saying "The following packages will be removed by the update: linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic (5.15.0-25.25)", with "in order to install:" followed by a long list of software component. I click proceed and it start updating. After a while I get a message saying the update failed, with the specific message being "Update failed to install: Error while installing package: installed linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1".

Yes, I frequently reboot my system and this is happening after I rebooted it.

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           371M  1.7M  370M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       916G  206G  664G  24% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           371M   92K  371M   1% /run/user/1000
```

df -i

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs            474473    997   473476    1% /run
/dev/sda2      61022208 444242 60577966    1% /
tmpfs            474473      1   474472    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            474473      4   474469    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs             94894    124    94770    1% /run/user/1000
```

sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                    
Get:2 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]   
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:4 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]                                                                                                                                                              
Get:5 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [277 kB]                                                                                                                                                       
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.4 kB]                                                                                                                                                
Get:7 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [124 kB]                                                                                                                                                        
Get:8 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [73.3 kB]                                                                                                                                               
Get:9 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [116 kB]                                                                                                                                                   
Get:10 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [46.3 kB]                                                                                                                                                  
Get:11 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [91.8 kB]                                                                                                                                          
Get:12 http://lb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,196 B]                                                                                                                                        
Fetched 1,060 kB in 17s (61.5 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
62 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================================-===========================================-============-================================================================================
rH  linux-image-5.15.0-25-generic                 5.15.0-25.25                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic                 5.15.0-30.31                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic                 5.15.0-33.34                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo                   1:22.04.10                                  all          graphical boot animation and logger - kubuntu-logo theme
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Which kernel version are you running now? Which error messages do you get? Did you try rebooting and the proceeding? (Yes rebooting is needed when a new kernel is installed.) Please include in your post.

Comment: please [edit] your question and show us `df -h;df -i` also `sudo apt update` and `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: Dear Artur and nobody, I edited my original question with the information you requested.